# How to integrate Ruby with bootstrap search bar

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I am trying to integrate Ruby code into the bootstrap search bar.

Here's my code thus far:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
 </form>

# Search function
<%= form_tag deals_path, :method => "get" do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder:"Search a deal name %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

Comment: Please describe the desired behavior. "Integrate" is not enough. Are you struggling with the css? Or the ruby backend code?

Comment: Also, do you want the typeahead to work on this? Details please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <%=form_tag deals_path,{:method=>'get', class:"navbar-form navbar-left", role:"search"}  do%>
     <div class="form-group">
        <%=text_field_tag :search,"",class:"form-control",placeholder:"Search"%>
     </div>
    <%=submit_tag 'Seach' ,class:"btn btn-default "%>
 <%end%>
```